# syntax checking for config files

Tags: linux, bash, perl, scripting

I have a requirement to check the syntax of some config files.

The format of the config is as below:

```
[sect1]
sect1file1
sect1file2
[sect1_ends]

[sect2]
sect2file1
sect2file2
[sect2_ends]
```

My requirement is to check the for start of `sect1` which is inside square brackets `[sect1]`, then check that the files `sect1file1` and `sect1file2` exist, then check for the end of `sect1` by reading `sect1_ends` inside square braces `[sect1_ends]`. Then repeat the same for `sect2`, and so on.

There is already a set of section names which are permitted. My objective is to check whether the section names are in the list, and whether the syntax is without any error.

I tried using

```
 perl -lne 'print $1 while (/^\[(.*?)\]$/g)' <config filename>
```

but I'm not sure how to check and go through the file.

Comment: First get clear what your checks are. Then decide the tool. Will `grep` for the sections and comparing with a list of sections be ok, or should you make a small progam with `awk` of `perl`.

Comment: thanks @walter but **grep** wont help because i have to check at *start* that **sect1** is contained within a square bracket and is present in the list of permitted section names, after that is validated, i need to check that the *files* defined for that **sect1** exists and at last check **sect1** has been *terminated* properly using *sect1_ends* within square brackets. Then keep track of **sect1** syntax is *valid or not* and proceed to **sect2** even if it is *invalid* and at last i need to *print all the invalid sytax sections* for the user to correct.

Comment: Try with something like `while read -r linel do ... done < inputfile` with things in your loop like `inSection="sect1"` and `if [ -f "${inSection}file1" ]`

Comment: many thanks @walter i have started working by reading line by line with `while` and based on the content im deciding what should be done but still the keeping track of invalid `sect` and continuing through other parts is little complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am happy to see you have tried. Try again with this prototype:

```
while read -r line; do
   if [ ${#line} -eq 0 ]; then
      continue # ignore empty lines
   fi
   if [[ "${line}" = \[*\] ]]; then
      echo "Line with [...]"
      if [ -n "${inSection}" ]; then
         if [ "${line}" = "${inSection/]/_ends]}" ]; then
            echo "End of section"
            unset inSection
         else
            echo "Invalid endtag ${line} while processing ${inSection}"
            exit 1
         fi
      else
         echo "Start of new section ${line}"
         inSection="${line}"
      fi
   else
      if [ -f "${line}" ]; then
         echo "OK file ${line}"
      else
         echo "NOK file ${line}"
      fi
   fi
done < inputfile
```

Comment: wow that logic worked like a charm, i have improvised it to include more of my requirements.Thanks a ton.

Comment: I am happy this works out. You can accept the answer and put the ton on your bank account.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good, but [-n reads lines from standard input](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#-n) (STDIN). You need to feed your config file into STDIN to pass it to your script:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 while (/^\[(.*?)\]$/g)' <config.ini
```

Alternate option would be using [-p](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#-p).

Comment: Thanks @sebastian that solves capturing lines starting and ending with square brackets which will help in capturing `[sect]` and `[sect_ends]` but im not sure how the logic should flow through.As suggested by @walter i have started working with a `while` loop that reads line by line, decides if its a valid `sect start`and then go through all following lines till `sect_ends` and validate if `sect_ends` corresponds to `sect start`